# How to write a complete solution to $i=\cos x$?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Here's my solution. But I think there's more to it.

$$i=\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
$$2i= e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$$

Multiply both sides by $e^{ix}$ and rearrange.

$$0=\left(e^{ix}\right)^2-2ie^{ix}+1$$

Solve the quadratic.

$$e^{ix}=\frac{-(-2i)\pm\sqrt{(-2i)^2-4(1)(1)}}{2(1)}$$
$$=\frac{2i\pm\sqrt{-8}}{2}=i(1\pm \sqrt2)$$

Take the log of both sides

$$ix=\ln[i(1\pm i\sqrt2)]$$
$$x=-i\ln[i(1\pm \sqrt2)]$$
$$=-i[\ln i+\ln(1\pm\sqrt2)]$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln(1\pm\sqrt2)$$

Wolfram Alpha shows a solution equivalent to:

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln(1+\sqrt2)$$

However, I am wondering about:

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln(1-\sqrt2)$$

Furthermore, I suspect we need to add $+2n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes you're on the right track. Just think it through so you get all the possibilities.

Comment: Maybe convert $i(1\pm\sqrt{2})$ to polar form $\large e^{ix}=(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}2+2ik\pi}$ then it's just a matter of identification.

Comment: There may be an alternative approach too, let $z=x+iy$, then $$\cos z = \cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)=i.$$
Since $\cosh y\neq 0$ for real $y$ then we need $\cos x = 0$ so $x = \pi(2k-1)/2$. You could then substitute that into the other term and solve $(-1)^k\sinh(y)=1$.